Gu10 LED and TP8514
I have this lightbulb fit correctly in the socket 8514 LED 9W:
https://www.tp24.com/8514-led-10w-frosted-gls-l1-cap.html
[TP8514
I would like to replace it with its 4000K equivalent. I brought the GU10 led replacement:
https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/solhetta-led-bulb-gu10-345-lumen-10518484/
and
https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/solhetta-led-bulb-gu10-230-lumen-10518479/

The GU10 goes into the socket correctly, switches on, but does not hold in place. Meaning it switches on while my hand is holding it :D Is this the correct replacement or not? I have tried multiple sockets and multiple GU10 bulbs - same story.


The prongs look slightly different to me.  Can you post a side-by-side pic?

Is the lamp too wide to fit all the way into the socket? It could be a wider socket is needed, or narrower lamp.

@DrMoishePippik i uploaded a picture of the holder

@bissi, that image shows no depth. You can determine from the "feel" when inserting the lamp if the shell is hitting the edge of the holder, rather than the base bottoming out against the socket.

@Huesmann I uploaded it now

@bissi hard to tell for sure from the pics, but the prongs do look different to me.  (A side-by-side shot would be better.)
